# Virtual WebRTC - want to deploy android app on cloud and wants to connect using WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc

Setup:

1. Deploy Android app with WebRTC capability on cloud [Cloud does not have mic and camera]
2. Install another android app on physical device
3. Use VNC client to connect to Android app installed in cloud
4. Using VNC channel, cloud android app connects to a physical app installed on android device

My question here:

1. Is there any way we can send audio/video/mic info from VCN client to android app installed on cloud?
2. If we can send this information, is they any way,  Android app installed on cloud, can re-transmit the audio/video/mic data to the android user installed on physical device ?

I have tried but its not working